# Count amount of rows that has a value larger then 0 in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following scenario:

```
   N
4| 2
5| 3
6| 0
```

I want a formula to look through whole column N and then give me the amount of rows that has a value larger then 0 in its cell.

For example this function does it for cell N4:

```
=IF(VALUE(N4)>0;ROWS(N4);0)
---> Returns: 1
```

But I want to do this for ALL rows in column N. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIF():

```
=COUNTIF(N:N,">0")
```

The [COUNTIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) function counts the number of time the range equals the criterion.